# throw exception

Tags: java, exception, throw

Why can't you throw an InterruptedException in the following way:

```
try {
    System.in.wait(5) //Just an example
} catch (InterruptedException exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
 //On this next line I am confused as to why it will not let me throw the exception
    throw exception;
}
```

I went to http://java24hours.com, but it didn't tell me why I couldn't throw an InterruptedException.
If anyone knows why, **PLEASE** tell me! I'm desperate! :S

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: It says: unreported exception java.lang.InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can only throw it if the method you're writing *declares* that it throws `InterruptedException` (or a base class).

For example:

```
public void valid() throws InterruptedException {
  try {
    System.in.wait(5) //Just an example
  } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
    throw exception;
  }
}

// Note the lack of a "throws" clause.
public void invalid() {
  try {
    System.in.wait(5) //Just an example
  } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
    throw exception;
  }
}
```

You should read up on *checked exceptions* for more details.

(Having said this, calling `wait()` on `System.in` almost certainly isn't doing what you expect it to...)

Comment: Or, he could deal with the exception in the `catch` block. Anyway, good explanation of how exceptions work.

Answer (score 3):

There are two kinds of exceptions in Java: *checked* and *unchecked* exceptions.

For checked exceptions, the compiler checks if your program handles them, either by catching them or by specifying (with a `throws` clause) that the method in which the exception might happen, that the method might throw that kind of exception.

Exception classes that are subclasses of `java.lang.RuntimeException` (and `RuntimeException` itself) are unchecked exceptions. For those exceptions, the compiler doesn't do the check - so you are not required to catch them or to specify that you might throw them.

Class `InterruptedException` is a checked exception, so you must either catch it or declare that your method might throw it. You are throwing the exception from the `catch` block, so you must specify that your method might throw it:

```
public void invalid() throws InterruptedException {
    // ...
```

Exception classes that extend `java.lang.Exception` (except `RuntimeException` and subclasses) are checked exceptions.

See Sun's [Java Tutorial about exceptions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) for detailed information.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that you can also throw instances of non-Exception classes derived from Throwable. These are exceptions but not Exceptions :)

Comment: @Jon, yes, but that's a more advanced subject that goes beyond what the poster asks, I didn't want to make this a complete course on exceptions in Java...

Answer (score 0):

InterruptedException is not a RuntimeException so it must be caught or checked (with a throws clause on the method signature).  You can only throw a RuntimeException and not be forced by the compiler to catch it.

Comment: Well, not quite - you can declare that you're going to throw it to force the *caller* to catch or rethrow it.

Comment: I mentioned that in the first sentence, my second sentence should read "... and not be forced by the compiler to 'handle' it."  That would have been more clear.